# Are there applications of model theory to category theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

There seems to be a decent amount of literature connecting category theory and model theory. (See for instance the paper *Classifying Spaces and the Lascar Group*). But for the most part, it seems to be category-theoretic methods applied to model theory. I'm wondering if there is any research in the opposite direction, applying model theory to category theory. For instance, has there been any research into categories as two sorted structures? If so, has this research been fruitful, or is it not particularly interesting for some reason or another?

Comment: To me the biggest part of the interaction between category theory and model theory is about translating things that have been in model theory years ago into category theoretic language (because model theory is a much older topic), as such I see them more as "application of ideas coming from model category to category theory". But, For example, the sort of "theory" that categories are a model of (quasi-algebraic theories) are already very well understood in category theoretic language (it corresponds to the theory of locally finitely presentable categories) (...)

Comment: (...) so that no "model theory" is needed (at least not anymore) to study anything about them - everything is done purely categorically. But these notions have probably been inspired by model theory to some extent.

Comment: I am in total agreement with what @SimonHenry has said. Nevertheless, I suggest the question deserves serious consideration: Model Theory has made some valuable  contributions to certain other disciplines, so can it do similar things for category theory? As a devout categorist, I actually believe that, whatever those things might be, category theory ought to be able to reproduce and improve on them in its own terms. But I repeat, the question is worthy of consideration.

Comment: Absolutely - my point is more that the main reason we don't see more of these is because every time a category theorist (and I am definitely including myself here) see a model-theoretic result that could be useful in category theory, the first things he tries to do is to rephrase it in a purely category-theoretic language, because that's what category theorist understand best.